# CSS Triangle Flip On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, geometry, transform

Ok so i have this triangle div and when i click it, it only rotates 180deg. Ok so far so good but if i click it again it stays the same here is my code.

```
$('.Triangle').click(function()
{
    var Location = $('.Triangle').offset().left;
    $('#Account').css({"left" : Location});
    $('#Account').slideToggle('fast');
    $('.Triangle').css({"transform" : "rotate(180deg)"});
});
```

Comment: yes it's supposed to do another 180 degree rotation

Comment: You want to rotate it back to its initial value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'transform' style sets the rotation of the element from it's original position. When you click it the first time, it rotates the element from `0deg` to `180deg`. When you click it again, it changes the rotation from `180deg` to `180deg`.

You need to keep a counter for the number of clicks and multiply that by your rate of rotation. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var count = 1;
$('.Triangle').click(function() {
    var Location = $('.Triangle').offset().left;
    $('#Account').css({"left" : Location});
    $('#Account').slideToggle('fast');
    $('.Triangle').css({"transform" : "rotate(" + (180 * count++) + "deg)"});
});`
```

Comment: Does this work properly if you have more than one _HTMLElement_ with class _Triangle_ ?

Answer (score 4):

Transforms don't work that way (i.e. you can't apply it twice).  You have to keep track of state:

```
$(".Triangle").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).data('flipped') {
         $(this).data('flipped', false).css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
$('.Triangle').click(function() {
    i++;
    var Location = $('.Triangle').offset().left;
    $('#Account').css({"left" : Location});
    $('#Account').slideToggle('fast');
    $('.Triangle').css({"transform" : "rotate(" + (i % 2 ? 0 : 180 + "deg)"});
});
```